# jQuery UI resizable expanding div

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I have a div that is setup to use the jQuery ui resizable. It all works as expected except there is unwanted space between the outline and the border because the resizable divs are expanding the .test div. To date I have been using overflow: hidden to get around this issue. That has worked out well, however, I now have an instance where I am using a style using the :after, which gets cut off. How would I get around this?

This appears to be an issue in Firefox.

CSS:

```
.test {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    outline: 1px dashed #9a9a9a;
    /* overflow: hidden; */
}

.test:after {
    border: 11px solid transparent;
    border-top-color: #000;
    border-bottom: 0;
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    bottom: -11px;
}
```

Here is a [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/65cay7gt/)

Comment: What do you mean by *"css outline has unwanted padding"*..? `outline` is a property, not an element, it can't have `padding`. Also, `::after` looks perfectly fine to me in latest version of chrome... Can you post a screenshot of the issue..?

Comment: my 2 cents: http://jsfiddle.net/d6p2o6ya/ - just add one more container and make the child resizeable. The divs that JQuery appends seems to add the padding you want to remove...

Comment: The resizable needs to be on the div.  What I mean is that there is unwanted space between the outline and the border.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a bug that has stuck around for years with Firefox.  While outline-offset is an option, it would need to be applied to Firefox only and would need to account for all things that overflow.  A better option is to do this:

```
.test {
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

.test:before {
   content: '';
   position: absolute;
   top: -1px; /* Set to offset top border width */
   left: -1px; /* Set to offset left border width */
   right: -1px; /* Set to offset right border width */
   bottom: -1px;/* Set to offset bottom border width */
   outline: 1px dashed #9a9a9a;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/65cay7gt/9/

Answer (score 1):

please add these line to your jquery after resizable function

```
$("div.ui-resizable-n").css('top','0px');
$("div.ui-resizable-e").css('right','0px');
$("div.ui-resizable-s").css('bottom','0px');
$("div.ui-resizable-w").css('left','0px');
```

so that it would become

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".test").resizable({
        handles: "n, e, s, w"
    });

    $("div.ui-resizable-n").css('top','0px');
    $("div.ui-resizable-e").css('right','0px');
    $("div.ui-resizable-s").css('bottom','0px');
    $("div.ui-resizable-w").css('left','0px');
});
```

Comment: I've upvoted as this is an option, but still doesn't handle the :after the same as other browsers.  My solution above seems to be the best way until Firefox fixes the bug in the browser.

Comment: it worked fine at my end, however i recommend @fanfavorite answer as it does not involve any jquery :-)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly you are referring to the extra space above and below your text?
Because you use the p tag in your html most browsers have default padding/margins to add before and after each paragraph. To change that spacing you can simply add another css class:

```
.test p{
margin:0px;
}
```

That targets any text inside of a paragraph tag that is inside something identified by the class "test." Note that it changes all the margin to 0px, if you want specific amounts on different sides you can use margin-left, margin-right, margin-top, margin-bottom, or use a short hand.

Comment: Thats not what I am looking for.  I mean the space outside the border, inside the outline.

Comment: @fanfavorite hmm well I am not positive what you are talking about. In my browsers the dashed line and the outline are touching and there is no space between them

Comment: @Kirsten Vogler is right, in chrome there is no space between outline and border, but in firefox it is showing space in between outline and border.

Comment: Your right ZAZ, IE and Chrome are fine, Firefox is the culprit.  Any idea on a fix for Firefox?

Comment: @fanfavorite I took a look at in in Firefox, you can add an additional line in the CSS called outline-offset and give it a -5px value and that will change where the outline appears. You will want to add something so that it will only change when it's using firefox. The problem I noticed is that the triangle you have on the bottom forces the outline to be even further. You may want to consider making that a separate div to avoid the spacing on the bottom.

Comment: i just saw the css in firebug and in firefox its adding -5px of padding to top, left, bottom and right of the divs added by jquery uiresizable in case of firefox